# To-Do List in JavaScript - After deleting a task, you can't select another one properly

Tags: javascript, list

This is my first big project and I am making a to-do list and everything worked smoothly so far but I just noticed a really unpleasant problem.
So, I decided to make an option to edit a task by clicking on it - you get options like moving it up and down, renaming it and even delete it. I tested the delete feature and it turns out, it doesn't work as intended.
When I want to remove a task for the first time, everything works well.
[This is the to-do list. Let's remove task "d"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0tpS.png)
After clicking on the task, this menu opens:
[Let's click on "Delete"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yppg.png)
And voila! The task is gone. Let's remove another one. Like... the next one, for example.
[Let's click on task "f"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4RW8.png)
However, as you can see... [instead of "f", the "g" task is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjr0Z.png)
In conclusion, after deleting one task, trying to delete a task again results in inability to pick the task you want properly. Instead of working with the selected task, you work with the task that follows it after. Why does that happen? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
            var everyTask = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
            for (var q = 0; q < everyTask.length; q++) {  
                everyTask[q].addEventListener('click', ((h) => {          
                    return function() {
                        rememberThisTaskValue = h;
                    }
                })(q))
            }
            var allTasks = document.getElementsByClassName('regTask'); 
            for (var b = 0; b < allTasks.length; b++) {
                allTasks[b].onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                        this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    }
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                        this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    }
                    alert(rememberThisTaskValue);
                    temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeIn 0.18s forwards';
                    temporaryLayer.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
                    temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'blur(6px)';
                    body.appendChild(temporaryLayer);
                    var editor = document.createElement('div');
                    var editorTitle = document.createElement('h1');
                    var editorTitleNode = document.createTextNode('Edit task');
                    var editorSubTitle = document.createElement('h2');
                    // Styling
                    var editorSubTitleTextNodeContent = document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].innerHTML;
                    var editorSubTitleNode = document.createTextNode(editorSubTitleTextNodeContent);
                    var editorOptions = document.createElement('div');
                    var editorOptionsInput = document.createElement('input');
                    var editorOptionsDelete = document.createElement('button');
                    var editorOptionsDeleteNode = document.createTextNode('Delete');
                    var editorOptionsMove = document.createElement('button');
                    var editorOptionsMoveNode = document.createTextNode('Move');
                    var editorOptionsRename = document.createElement('button');
                    var editorOptionsRenameNode = document.createTextNode('Rename');
                    var editorOptionsCancel = document.createElement('button');
                    var editorOptionsCancelNode = document.createTextNode('Cancel');
                    // Styling
                    temporaryLayer.appendChild(editor);
                    editor.appendChild(editorTitle);
                    editorTitle.appendChild(editorTitleNode);
                    editor.appendChild(editorSubTitle);
                    editorSubTitle.appendChild(editorSubTitleNode);
                    editor.appendChild(editorOptions);
                    editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsRename);
                    editorOptionsRename.appendChild(editorOptionsRenameNode);
                    editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsMove);
                    editorOptionsMove.appendChild(editorOptionsMoveNode);
                    editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsDelete);
                    editorOptionsDelete.appendChild(editorOptionsDeleteNode);
                    editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsCancel);
                    editorOptionsCancel.appendChild(editorOptionsCancelNode);
                    editorOptionsCancel.onclick = function() {
                        // There is some styling here too but I am going to leave it just in case
                        editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        setTimeout (function() {
                            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                            editor.remove();
                            temporaryLayer.remove();
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                                this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                            }
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                                this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                            }
                        }, 180)
                    }
                    editorOptionsDelete.onclick = function() {
                        // This is the function that deletes a task
                        document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].remove();
                        var everyTask = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
                        for (var q = 0; q < everyTask.length; q++) {  
                            everyTask[q].addEventListener('click', ((h) => {          
                                return function() {
                                    var rememberThisTaskValue = h;
                                }
                            })(q))
                        }
                        editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        setTimeout (function() {
                            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                            editor.remove();
                            temporaryLayer.remove();
                        }, 180)
                    }
                    editorOptionsRename.onclick = function() {
                        editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        setTimeout (function() {
                            editor.remove();
                        }, 180)  
                        var nameChanger = document.createElement('div');
                        nameChanger.style.opacity = '0';
                        nameChanger.style.animation = "renameFadeIn 0.18s forwards";
                        var nameChangerTitle = document.createElement('h1');
                        var nameChangerTitleNode = document.createTextNode('Rename Task');
                        var nameChangerForm = document.createElement('form');
                        var nameChangerFormInput = document.createElement('input');
                        var nameChangerFormSubmit = document.createElement('button');
                        var nameChangerFormSubmitNode = document.createTextNode('Rename');
                        var nameChangerFormCancel = document.createElement('button');
                        var nameChangerFormCancelNode = document.createTextNode('Cancel');
                        // Styling
                        temporaryLayer.appendChild(nameChanger);
                        nameChanger.appendChild(nameChangerTitle);
                        nameChangerTitle.appendChild(nameChangerTitleNode);
                        nameChanger.appendChild(nameChangerForm);
                        nameChangerForm.appendChild(nameChangerFormInput);
                        nameChangerForm.appendChild(nameChangerFormSubmit);
                        nameChangerFormSubmit.appendChild(nameChangerFormSubmitNode);
                        nameChangerForm.appendChild(nameChangerFormCancel);
                        nameChangerFormCancel.appendChild(nameChangerFormCancelNode);
                        document.getElementById('taskRenameField').focus();
                        nameChangerFormCancel.onclick = function() {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            nameChanger.style.opacity = '1';
                            nameChanger.style.animation = 'changerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                            setTimeout (function() {
                                temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                                temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                                temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                                nameChanger.remove();
                                temporaryLayer.remove();
                                document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                                document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                                    this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                                }
                                document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                                    this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                                }
                            }, 180)
                        }
                        nameChangerFormSubmit.onclick = function() {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            if (!(nameChangerFormInput.value === "" || (!nameChangerFormInput.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length))) {
                                var taskReminder = nameChangerFormInput.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
                                document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].innerHTML = taskReminder;
                                nameChanger.style.opacity = '1';
                                nameChanger.style.animation = 'changerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                                temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                                setTimeout (function() {
                                    temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                                    temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                                    temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                                    nameChanger.remove();
                                    temporaryLayer.remove();
                                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                                        this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                                    }
                                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                                        this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                                    }
                                }, 180)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    editorOptionsMove.onclick = function() {
                        // This is the function that lets the user move elements but it's still unfinished, I barely started it
                        editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        stipText.style.animation = 'tipFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                        setTimeout (function() {
                            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                            temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                            editor.remove();
                            temporaryLayer.remove();
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                                this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                            }
                            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                                this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                            }
                        }, 180)

                        // Switch by clicking second task.
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I've tried:
- Using different variable names
- Removing the list and immediately putting in the page again. I though about resetting the counter that way and making the list work properly again.
- Implementing a variable that indicates if a task has been removed already. If this variable is positive, the `rememberThisTaskValue` variable reduces by 1.

None of those worked though.

Comment: Do you need to re-instantiate the `var` inside the options delete function? `var rememberThisTaskValue = h;`, or could you just remove the `var` to use the same global variable

Comment: Don't think so, I tried removing it but nothing happened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, in case someone is facing a similar problem and somehow managed to see this article, here's how I came up with an idea (though I am not 100% if it worked, time will show)
I'll try to explain why the list didn't work properly. So, let's say we remove the task with index [3]. Some people, probably, including me, expect the list to be this way now: [0], [1], [2], [4]. But task [4] has to go back and take the empty place. Task [5] has to take the place of [4]. This is honestly confusing to me but this is the only remaining idea I have. I still can't even imagine it in my head, but I'm probably on the right track...

So what did I do?

- Instead of deleting the element, I set it like this: `style.display = 'none'`
  I didn't delete it, just made it invisible, so spot [3] is still not empty and the other tasks have to remain at their places.
- Still, I want to delete these tasks completely to keep my list actually clean of unwanted or finished tasks. Since I added an option to close this list - every time you close it, I select all the tasks with this class name and `display:none` property and erase them. This shouldn't affect the list when I open it next time since all of the counters should reset.

**UPDATE (13.04.2020):**

So, unfortunately, the method above has some bad consequences if you want to implement functions like moving your tasks. It's also just not the best option. I want to share my progress and knowledge with the community though, so I'll happily show you my new solution:

```
function editTasks() {
    var everyTask = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
    for (var q = 0; q < everyTask.length; q++) {  
        everyTask[q].addEventListener('click', ((h) => {          
            return function() {
                rememberThisTaskValue = h;
            }
        })(q))
    }
    var allTasks = document.getElementsByClassName('regTask'); 
    for (var b = 0; b < allTasks.length; b++) {
        allTasks[b].onclick = function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            }
            alert(rememberThisTaskValue);
            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeIn 0.18s forwards';
            temporaryLayer.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
            temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'blur(6px)';
            body.appendChild(temporaryLayer);
            var editor = document.createElement('div');
            var editorTitle = document.createElement('h1');
            var editorTitleNode = document.createTextNode('Edit task');
            var editorSubTitle = document.createElement('h2');
            // Styling
            var editorSubTitleTextNodeContent = document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].innerHTML;
            var editorSubTitleNode = document.createTextNode(editorSubTitleTextNodeContent);
            var editorOptions = document.createElement('div');
            var editorOptionsInput = document.createElement('input');
            var editorOptionsDelete = document.createElement('button');
            var editorOptionsDeleteNode = document.createTextNode('Delete');
            var editorOptionsMove = document.createElement('button');
            var editorOptionsMoveNode = document.createTextNode('Move');
            var editorOptionsRename = document.createElement('button');
            var editorOptionsRenameNode = document.createTextNode('Rename');
            var editorOptionsCancel = document.createElement('button');
            var editorOptionsCancelNode = document.createTextNode('Cancel');
            // Styling
            temporaryLayer.appendChild(editor);
            editor.appendChild(editorTitle);
            editorTitle.appendChild(editorTitleNode);
            editor.appendChild(editorSubTitle);
            editorSubTitle.appendChild(editorSubTitleNode);
            editor.appendChild(editorOptions);
            editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsRename);
            editorOptionsRename.appendChild(editorOptionsRenameNode);
            editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsMove);
            editorOptionsMove.appendChild(editorOptionsMoveNode);
            editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsDelete);
            editorOptionsDelete.appendChild(editorOptionsDeleteNode);
            editorOptions.appendChild(editorOptionsCancel);
            editorOptionsCancel.appendChild(editorOptionsCancelNode);
            editorOptionsCancel.onclick = function() {
                // There is some styling here too but I am going to leave it just in case
                editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                setTimeout (function() {
                    temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                    temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                    temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                    editor.remove();
                    temporaryLayer.remove();
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseover = function() {
                        this.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    }
                    document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].onmouseout = function() {
                        this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                    }
                }, 180)
            }
            editorOptionsDelete.onclick = function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[rememberThisTaskValue].remove();
                            var nodes = listTaskViewer.childNodes;
                            for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
                                nodes[j].setAttribute('class', 'newSavedTask regTask');
                                nodes[j].style.animation = 'none';
                                nodes[j].style.opacity = '1';
                            }
                            localStorage.setItem("taskListSave", listTaskViewer.innerHTML);
                            listTaskViewer.innerHTML = 'none';
                            var theTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
                            for (var s = 0; s < theTasks.length; s++) {  
                                theTasks[s].style.animation = 'none';
                            }
                            listTaskViewer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("taskListSave");
                            for (var y = 0; y < savedTasks.length; y++) {
                                savedTasks[y].onmouseover = function() {
                                    this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
                                }
                                savedTasks[y].onmouseout = function() {
                                    this.style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
                                }
                                editTasks();
                            }
                            var everyTask = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
                            for (var q = 0; q < everyTask.length; q++) {  
                                everyTask[q].addEventListener('click', ((h) => {          
                                    return function() {
                                        var rememberThisTaskValue = h;
                                    }
                                })(q))
                            }
                            editor.style.animation = 'editorFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                            temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'layerFadeOut 0.18s forwards';
                            stipText.style.animation = 'tipFadeIn 0.18s forwards';
                            setTimeout (function() {
                                temporaryLayer.style.animation = 'none';
                                temporaryLayer.style.background = 'none';
                                temporaryLayer.style.backdropFilter = 'none';
                                editor.remove();
                                temporaryLayer.remove();
                            }, 180)
            }
            ...
}
```

So... how it works?
Well, it's important to say that the tasks are being deleted again, instead of just setting their display property to none.
As you can see, the whole chunk of code is inside a function now, called `editTasks()`, which is really important when writing the task delete function. When a task is deleted, the list gets saved under the same localStorage value I have used so far to save the tasks and append the saved value to the div again; the list is basically reloaded, kinda like a page refresh. I already knew that such refresh fixes the issue, but I never knew how to implement it on purpose / work without making the user close and open the list again just so they can delete a few tasks. When that refresh is done, the `editTasks()` function gets called and gives the tasks new indexes, which will help the list select tasks properly when clicked. The remaining code is just some styling and working with the animations to avoid confusion or strange-looking behaviour in my app. This isn't really something important since not all lists work like that, it's just some design features that are present on my list.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the event listener and the on click event are not synced anymore when a value is removed. It's best to put all of the work into one event listener to prevent discrepancy.

I would suggest removing this piece:

```js
var everyTask = document.querySelectorAll('.regTask');
for (var q = 0; q < everyTask.length; q++) {  
  everyTask[q].addEventListener('click', ((h) => {          
    return function() {
      rememberThisTaskValue = h;
    }
  })(q))
}
```

Then just using the index of the for-loop for your index instead of `rememberThisTaskValue`

`document.getElementsByClassName('regTask')[b].remove();`

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately, I can't try this right away because I'm away from my computer. I appreciate the help though, I will post an update later. :)

Comment: I edited the answer, this should hopefully work for you when you get the chance

Comment: Hello, this sadly didn't work. The b variable isn't recognized. I tried obtaining it by storing it in another variable called index in the beginning of the loop but it still didn't work. I won't be surprised if I'm just doing something wrong  and I am just failing to understand your idea, I'm extremely sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Okay, so I think I found alternative solution! I shared it below!